# JMS server issue with JBoss 7.2

Tags: jboss, jms, jboss7.x

We received below JMS error .

```
ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$6@39704d16)) AMQ212037: Connection failure has been detected: AMQ229014: Did not receive data from <IP:PORT>.
```

We get this message suddenly. I checked the source code and all the JMS connections are closed. Not able to reproduce the same. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This message is just indicating that a client exited without closing its connection or a connection was lost due to a network issue of some kind (i.e. the client didn't specifically close it). The broker will log this message so you can investigate if necessary. It's a fairly common message to see, and it should be logged at `WARN` level rather than at `ERROR`.